# Is "problems on [something]" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs

Would it be correct to say "problems on [something]"?

Like in this sentence:

> I enjoy helping my students to solve their problems on music performance.

Comment: You might get a more complete and helpful answer by doing a quick review of example usage on a page like this: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/problem#English.  After reading through that, we could easily clear up any further doubts you have.

Comment: Can you give us more context? Is this about students who are poor musical performers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the fuller context.

A problem ***with*** a musical performance is when a musician doesn't do a good job performing and needs to work on it.

> I'm a piano teacher. Many of my students get stage fright during recitals. I enjoy helping my students solve their problems **with** music performance.

A problem **on** a musical performance is something like a test question, a word puzzle *on the topic of* musical performance.

> I teach Art History. Many of my students have trouble answering music-related test questions. I enjoy helping them solve their problems **on** music performance.

Answer (score 3):

You would be understood, but as a native English speaker it sounds a little strange to me.

Usually in English we say that we have "problems **with**" something.

I would reword your example:

> I enjoy helping my students to solve problems **with** their musical
> performances.